Force float to break up bibliography
I have the following:

Two column document the last page of which ends halfway down the second column
Bibliography which is a bit more than 1 page
Floating full-page table which I want as close to the main text as possible
Page limitation

Hence, I want to begin the bibliography on the last page of the main text, then on the next page have the floating table, then on the last page have the rest of the bibliography. Because of the page limitation, \clearpage before the bibliography is not an option.
However, I can't find a way of forcing the float to be placed in the middle of the bibliography - whatever I try (including \afterpage{\clearpage} the float ends up at the end of the document.
Any ideas how to force the placement of a float on the next page, although we are in the middle of printing the bibliography?

Simply adding [p] to the float solved it...

floats go to float pages by default so you should not have needed to add p unless in code you had not shown you had removed that option previusly

I had [t] previously

and how were we to guess that? t means not p so is explicitly forcing any float larger than 70% of the page height to the end of the document unless flushed out with \clearpage Just remove the option.

@DavidCarlisle thanks for rubber ducking this.
